# Reset selected item to default on a query-Chosen list when bootstrap-modal popup form shows

Tags: jquery, select, reset, bootstrap-modal, jquery-chosen

How do you reset the selected item in drop down list on a modal popup form?

**EDIT:**
I am also using 
https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen

to manage the lists

This does not work:

```
<div class="col-lg-9">
    <select class="form-control input-sm" id="branch1">
        <option value="2185529A">Complaint</option>
        <option value="2385529A">Request</option>
        <option value="2585529A">Enquiry</option>
    </select>
</div>

<!-- scripts -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-modalmanager.js"></script>

$('#frmCase').on('show', function () {
    $.clearFormFields(this)
    $('#branch1').get(0).selectedIndex = 1;
    $('#branch2').get(0).selectedIndex = 1;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use event `shown.bs.modal` handler:

```
$('#yourModalIdOrSelector').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // 1 - select second option, set to 0 for first option
  $('#branch1').get(0).selectedIndex = 1;
  $('#branch2').get(0).selectedIndex = 1;
});
```

This event is fired when the modal has been made visible to the user. otherwise use `show.bs.modal`. Suite it with your code.

Comment: Yes, should be selected to default option.

Comment: I should have mentioned, i have the following:
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-modalmanager.js"></script>

Comment: this is your modal selector `$('#frmCase')`?

Comment: what version of bootstrap?

Comment: i am using bootstrap version 3.3

Comment: Then this `shown.bs.modal` event is yours. Try put alert inside those event. See whether those event getting called or not.

Comment: That affected most. Chosen plugin use heavy markup and have its own callback. Inspect element the select dropdown and see what element created next to it

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found a solution thanks to **@norlihazmey-ghazali** comments on *Chosen*

```
        $('#frmCase').on('shown', function (e) {
            $.clearFormFields(this)
            $('#branch1').get(0).selectedIndex  = 0;
            $('#branch2').get(0).selectedIndex  = 0;

            $('#branch1').trigger('chosen:updated');
            $('#branch2').trigger('chosen:updated');
        });
```